# Phonegap App running in background?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Is it possible to develop a background service for running in android devices and pack with my HTML/JavaScript application in PhoneGap Build?

I'm newbie to Phonegap and would like to know if it's possible only building locally or using PhoneGap Build.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

First you [create a background service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) in the Java/Android part of your PhoneGap app.

Then you can [communicate with the service via a PhoneGap Plug-In](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) in your PhoneGap "WebPage" by using JavaScript, e.g. The Plug-In implemenation (in Android) should be able to communicate with your service as singleton instance for example.

Comment: Hello Marcel! Thanks for the info. However, my other question is: After developing this service in Java, can I pack using Phonegap Build (online service) ?

Comment: No. This is a solution that only works on Java ... the part you upload on PhoneGap Build is the "web part". This works only locally (you have to implement the background service for each other platform manually).